# Second scanf in my function does not work

Tags: c, scanf

For some reason for my second `scanf` I get a segmentation fault. I'm especially confused since it works for the first one, but not the second `scanf`. Here's the relevant code:

```
int main() {
    NodePtr* startPtr = NULL;
    int base; 
    int number;
    
    getInputs(&base, &number);
    
    convertNumber(startPtr, base, number);
    return 0;
}

void getInputs(int* basePtr, int *numberPtr){
    printf("Please enter a base number system (2-10 or 16): ");
    scanf("%d", basePtr);
    
    while(*basePtr <2 || *basePtr >= 11 && *basePtr <=15 || *basePtr >= 17 ){
        printf("\nInvalid input! Please choose a base from 2-10, or 16: ");
        scanf("%d", basePtr);
    }
    
    printf("\nWhat decimal number would you like to convert: ");//asks for a number to convert
    printf("\n%p\n", numberPtr);
    scanf("%d", numberPtr);
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a base number system (2-10 or 16): 2
What decimal number would you like to convert:                                                                                         
0x7ffc6b599a34                                                                                                                         
3                                                                                                                                      
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: This does not segfault when I run it. Are you sure that it is not in the convertNumber function that you have not provided?

Comment: `startPtr ` is still `NULL` when you pass it to `convertNumber()`, whatever that does.

Comment: This code is incomplete. Can you edit the post to include the function definition for `convertNumber` and the struct definition for `NodePtr`

Comment: Also, I don't think it has anything to do with convertNumber function, because any printf command in between the two function calls dont work.

Comment: Try _declaring_ `void getInputs(int* basePtr, int *numberPtr);` first, before `main()`, before calling it.

Comment: @CannonReyes " I don't think it has anything to do with convertNumber function" --> For now, comment out `convertNumber(startPtr, base, number);` --> `// convertNumber(startPtr, base, number);`

Answer (score 0):

In my program I had a printf command in between the two function calls (not shown here) to test whether it was the first or the second function call that was causing the issue. When I ran it it didn't print the printf statement in main, so I assumed it was the first function call causing the problem.

It turns out that it was actually the null pointer for the second function call, although I'm not sure why it wouldn't print the printf statement in between the two function calls, but the getInputs function does actually work. Thanks!

Comment: The `stdout` stream is buffered. You need to use `fflush(stdout)` after each call, for it to be any use as a debugging tool.